# spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb Map enum to String in the entity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have an entity:

```
@Document(collection = "test")
public class Test{

    @Id
    @Field("_id")
    private String id;

    @Field("type")
    private Type type;

...

}
```

it is enum:

```
public enum Type {
    ONE("one"), TWO("two"), THREE("three");

    private final String name;

    Type (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

But mongo collection has a String type of "type" field. How can I convert my enum to String?

```
findAllByType(Type type);
```

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. So first clear it, then downvote.

Answer (score 0):

**Spring Data MongoDB** takes care of conversion from **enum** to **String** type. Just below code is enough to achieve your requirement.

```
public interface TestRepository extends MongoRepository<Test, String> {
    List<Test> findAllByType(Type type);
}
```

Given your **enum** class, you ensure that your collection contains the **type** field values in `CAPS` i.e., "ONE", "TWO", "THREE" etc., not as "one", "two", "three" etc. If it is `not in CAPS`, your query might not return anything.

Comment: I am looking for something like this https://thorben-janssen.com/jpa-21-type-converter-better-way-to/ but for spring mongo
Of course, I know that MongoRepository can work with an enum, but I wrote that I already have a collection with the String type, but I want to use it as an enum in my code.